# ZF2 form validation is empty validations always fails

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

Hiho,

i have a problem with a ZF2 Form. 
Every time I submit  it I got the following error:

```
(result of $form->isValid() and var_dump($form->getMessages());

array (size=1)
'imagecode' => 
  array (size=1)
    'isEmpty' => string 'Value is required and can't be empty' (length=36)
```

The following is the 'imagecode' - formfieldcode:

```
public function __construct($name = null)
{
    parent::__construct('advert');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'imagecode',
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        'attributes' => array(
            'required' => 'required',
        ),
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Bannercode:'
        ),
    ));
```

And the Validator:

```
public function getInputFilter()
{
    if (!$this->_inputFilter) {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory     = new InputFactory();
```

...

```
        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'       => 'imagecode',
            'required'   => true,
            'filters'    => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'min'      => '3',
                        'max'      => '5000',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )));

        $this->_inputFilter = $inputFilter;
    }

    return $this->_inputFilter;
}
```

The other fields working correct and are correct validated but not the Textarea.

At last the ControllerCode:

```
$advert  = $service->getAdvertById($id);
        $form    = $service->getAdvertForm();
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        $form->bind($advert);

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $filter = new AdvertFilter();
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            $form->setInputFilter($filter->getInputFilter());
```

After this the validation is failing and I don't know why.
I hope that any one can help me.

Comment: Can you show us what are your trying to input in this field? Some sample post data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out.
I trying to input html code so that the

```
array('name' => 'StripTags')
```

removed it.

Sometimes it is so simple ._.'

Answer (score 0):

Look this line :

```
'required' => 'required,
```

and....
change to:

```
'required' => 'required',
```

Comment: look 'required' => 'required HERE NOT HAVE ''''''',